# Comparing doubles

Tags: c++11, comparison

I need to compare to double variables like this

```
if (distance <= radius)
```

both distance and radius are doubles and I remember in class how to use epsilon comparisons for checking equality but how would I do it for <= or >?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow, are you question blocked there? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Maybe [boost](https://www.google.com/search?q=boost%20arbitrary%20precision) has something that might help?

Answer (score 4):

An epsilon is not relevant when you are checking which floating point value is bigger. It's only needed for equality, where (due to precision issues) your math may create two values which are supposed to be equal, but are slightly off.

Comment: The question is about "less than or equal to" which could involve an epsilon. However, depending on the specific application, arbitrary-precision arithmetic _might_ be more appropriate than floating point and would make an epsilon mostly irrelevant.

Comment: For <= I suppose you could want to consider a small epsilon above to be equal, but I can't think of a real use case.

Comment: Same here. The question is technically valid but I am at a loss to explain _why_ one might need this. Regardless of the use case, I can think of better ways to do it that sidestep the requirement.

Comment: Thank you, to get around <= I just used > and swapped the truth value. I'm writing a program to check if a point is in an ellipse the code I posted wasn't the exact code I used since it is homework. I just didn't know if epsilons only applied to equality.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your definition of "<=".

If you want to declare them equal if they are within a certain distance of each other, then you would do:

```
if ((a < (b+epsilon)) do_whatever();
```

This is counterintuitive, since it would accept a > b by less than epsilon, which is probably not what you want.  But it might be.

In general, talking about floating-point (which includes doubles) equality is meaningless.